# Network Service App Pool Identity Denied Access to Remove users from group in AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, network-service

When I publish my application to my web server.  In IIS Manager, I give the application pool that I'm using an Identity of `Network Service`.

In my application, I am giving functionality to remove/add users from a specific Active Directory group.  Here is the code:

```
public static void RemoveUserFromGroup(string userId, string groupName)
{
    try
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomain"))
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
            group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
            group.Save();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        throw E;

    }
}
```

This works when I test local because my account has admin privileges when dealing with AD.  So just to check, on page load I am logging the Windows User Name by doing this:

```
var thread = '@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name';
console.log(thread);
```

That leads to `NT AUTHORITYNETWORK SERVICE`.  But when I try to remove a user from the AD group.. I get:

> Access is denied

How do I give `Network Service` access to do this?  Or is there an alternate way to do this?

Comment: Why did you delete your other question just to dupe it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355257/removing-user-from-ad-not-working-when-app-is-published

Comment: @Amy because I found a little more information and could provide that in a more clear question rather than someone having to scroll through you and I's comments to get more information.

Comment: In the future **edit the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" is a built-in **machine level** Windows account which is used by a wide variety of processes, not just IIS (load the Services control panel (Start > Run > "services.msc") and take a look at the "Log On As" column. You'll see several Windows components running under this identity. Because of this, you shouldn't change the permissions and rights of the account - you may not be able to do so!

What you can do is create a domain user with the appropriate rights and configure the application pool to run with that identity. Alternatively, it looks like one of the [constructors for `PrincipalContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341016(v=vs.110).aspx) allows for a username and password to be specified, although this would mean you'd need to store the username and password somewhere yourself.

Comment: I assume you mean instead of using the options from `Built-in account`.. I would create a `Custom account`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, yup

Comment: That allows me to just create a username and password right there?  Then I have to find that username somehow and give it the correct privileges?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid *"What you can do is create a domain user with the appropriate rights and configure the application pool to run with that identity."*

Comment: I have created a domain account.. and added that account to the same groups that I am a part of.. and I still get `access is denied`.. but when I use my personal account.. it works...